# Calculate percentages / proportions of values by group using data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I have a `data.table` that looks like the following:

```
x, y, sum(count)
1, 1, 3
1, 2, 7
1, 3, 8
2, 1, 4
2, 2, 3
2, 3, 10
```

And so on. It's keyed by `x` and `y` and I did a `sum` on a `count` column. I would like to break it down into percentages by the values of x so that it becomes:

```
x, y, percentage(counts)
1, 1, 16.7
1, 2, 38.9
1, 3, 44.4
2, 1, 23.5
2, 2, 17.6
2, 3, 58.8
```

So that the total percentage per `x` value totals 100%. I am doing this using the `data.table` package. Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: I am not sure your request matches the data you display "So that the total percentage per x value totals 100%": would that not give about 16.666% for the first line instead of 37.5% ?

Comment: I believe you are trying to aggregate in two steps. 1) Compute sum() for each group. 2) Calculate percentages. You could aggregate and calculate percentages in one step. [Check out this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20794649/aggregate-using-data-table).

Comment: @HansRoggeman I can do mathz...thanks! *^-^*

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I don't quite understand the `data.table` solution already posted, so I would do it like this (and I would change the name of the columns to not have parentheses to avoid lots of backtick quoting(!) of column names):

```
dt[ , `percentage(counts)` := `sum(count)` / sum( `sum(count)` ) * 100 , by = "x" ]
#   x y sum(count) percentage(counts)
#1: 1 1          3           16.66667
#2: 1 2          7           38.88889
#3: 1 3          8           44.44444
#4: 2 1          4           23.52941
#5: 2 2          3           17.64706
#6: 2 3         10           58.82353
```

Comment: See also `prop.table()`

Comment: As haldey says you can use the `prop.table()` function, e.g. `dt[ , per := prop.table(\`sum(count)\`) , by = "x"]`.

Answer (score 2):

On your original (not summed) data, you could do:

```
allsums <- sum(data[, counts])
data[, percentage = 100*sum(counts)/allsums, by="x,y"]
```

Or on your summed data:

```
allsums <- sum(data[, sums])
data[, percentage = 100*sums/allsums, by="x,y"]
```

Comment: I hope I do not misunderstand you, but with your second output I receive the following:

>   x y percentage

> 1: 1 1   8.571429

> 2: 1 2  20.000000

> 3: 1 3  22.857143

> 4: 2 1  11.428571

> 5: 2 2   8.571429

> 6: 2 3  28.571429

As for your first suggestion, I do not have just the counts.