# Calculate Percentage and other functions using data.table

Tags: r, data.table, dplyr

I want to apply aggregate functions and percentage function to column. I found threads that discuss aggregation ([Calculating multiple aggregations with lapply(.SD, ...) in data.table R package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24151602/calculating-multiple-aggregations-with-lapply-sd-in-data-table-r-package)) and threads that discuss percentage ([How to obtain percentages per value for the keys in R using data.table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20910659/how-to-obtain-percentages-per-value-for-the-keys-in-r-using-data-table) and [Use data.table to calculate the percentage of occurrence depending on the category in another column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33946334/use-data-table-to-calculate-the-percentage-of-occurrence-depending-on-the-catego)), but not both.

Please note that I am looking for `data.table` based methods. `dplyr` wouldn't work on actual data set.

Here's the code to generate sample data:

```
set.seed(10)
  IData <- data.frame(let = sample( x = LETTERS, size = 10000, replace=TRUE), numbers1 = sample(x = c(1:20000),size = 10000), numbers2 = sample(x = c(1:20000),size = 10000))
  IData$let<-as.character(IData$let)

  data.table::setDT(IData)
```

Here's the **code to generate output** using `dplyr`

```
Output <- IData %>%
    dplyr::group_by(let) %>%
    dplyr::summarise(numbers1.mean = as.double(mean(numbers1)),numbers1.median = as.double(median(numbers1)),numbers2.mean=as.double(mean(numbers2)),sum.numbers1.n = sum(numbers1)) %>%
    dplyr::ungroup() %>%
    dplyr::mutate(perc.numbers1 = sum.numbers1.n/sum(sum.numbers1.n)) %>%
    dplyr::select(numbers1.mean,numbers1.median,numbers2.mean,perc.numbers1)
```

**Sample Output (header)**
If I run `head(output)`, I would get:

```
  let numbers1.mean numbers1.median numbers2.mean perc.numbers1
  <chr>         <dbl>           <dbl>         <dbl>         <dbl>
    N     10320.951         10473.0      9374.435    0.03567927
    H      9683.590          9256.5      9328.035    0.03648391
    L     10223.322         10226.0      9806.210    0.04005400
    S      9922.486          9618.0     10233.849    0.03678742
    C      9592.620          9226.0      9791.221    0.03517997
    F     10323.867         10382.0     10036.561    0.03962035
```

Here's what I tried using `data.table` (unsuccessfully)

```
  IData[, as.list(unlist(lapply(.SD, function(x) list(mean=mean(x),median=median(x),sum=sum(x))))), by=let, .SDcols=c("numbers1","numbers2")] [,.(Perc = numbers1.sum/sum(numbers1.sum)),by=let]
```

I have 2 Questions:

a) How can I solve this using `data.table`?

b) I have seen above threads have used `prop.table`. Can someone please guide me how to use this function?

I would sincerely appreciate any guidance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use the similar approach with `data.table`

```
res <- IData[, .(numbers1.mean = mean(numbers1),
          numbers1.median = median(numbers1),
          numbers2.mean=mean(numbers2),
          sum.numbers1.n = sum(numbers1)), let
          ][, perc.numbers1 := sum.numbers1.n/sum(sum.numbers1.n)
           ][, c("let", "numbers1.mean",  "numbers1.median", 
                        "numbers2.mean", "perc.numbers1"), with = FALSE]

head(res)
#    let numbers1.mean numbers1.median numbers2.mean perc.numbers1
#1:   N     10320.951         10473.0      9374.435    0.03567927
#2:   H      9683.590          9256.5      9328.035    0.03648391
#3:   L     10223.322         10226.0      9806.210    0.04005400
#4:   S      9922.486          9618.0     10233.849    0.03678742
#5:   C      9592.620          9226.0      9791.221    0.03517997
#6:   F     10323.867         10382.0     10036.561    0.03962035
```

Comment: sorry for dumb question: if I don't assign the above code to `res` nothing happens. This is unlike `dplyr` in which if I don't assign anything, `dplyr` would output the result on the screen, but in above case with `data.table`, this doesn't happen. Why is it so? I'd appreciate your thoughts.

Comment: @watchtwoer  If you check the first `[]`, we are doing summarising and not creating a column in the original dataset.  By assigning `:=` only we create a new column.  But, in this code, that happens after the first `[]`, so it won't update the original data.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, and my apologies for being unclear. I think I have got the `:=` part, and the difference between the first `[]` and the second `[]` .  If I take out `res <-` part (the assignment to res), I am not sure why the above code doesn't print anything on the screen. The only way to see the result is to execute `res`. In contrast, `dplyr` always prints result if nothing is assigned. I hope my question is clear this time. I'd appreciate your help.

Comment: @watchtower Regarding the printing, it is because of the `:=`.  you need `[]` at the end i.e. `with =FALSE][]`

Comment: That works! So, the take-away for me is that after using `:=` (reference operator), I must use `[]` to print. Am I correct? `dplyr` by design doesn't work using references so it prints by default. Is my understanding correct? Thanks for your support and help.

Comment: @watchtower Yes, if you want to print the output on screen.  Or else just assign it to a new object